# How to filter when two columns both equal a value

Tags: sql

For example:

```
SELECT 
t.a
,t.b
,t.c

FROM table t
WHERE (t.a and t.c) = 'value'
```

If i just do two lines in the where clause its not quite right, i only need to select when they are BOTH the same and not when its one or the other

Answer (score 1):

Just change this

```
WHERE (t.a and t.c) = 'value'
```

to this

```
WHERE t.a='value' and t.c='value'
```

Comment: I decided that I prefer your solution, because it is index-friendly.

Comment: Then you taught me something. :)